# Build a hash with values from two other hashes?

Tags: perl, hash

I have two hashes which have similar keys but different values.

I want to build a third hash with all the keys of the first hash and all the values of the second.

If the second hash doesn't have an element for any given key then the corresponding value for the resultant hash should be blank or `undef`.

For example, with these hashes

```
my %hash1 = (
  BLUE   => 30,
  GREEN  => 40,
  INDIGO => 12,
  ORANGE => 56,
  RED    => 45,
  VIOLET => 25,
  YELLOW => 10,
);

my %hash2 = (
  BLUE   => ["command1", "command2", "command3", "command4"],
  GREEN  => ["Windows", "Linux", "Unix", "Mac"],
  INDIGO => ["Air", "Earth", "Sky", "Water", "Fire"],
  RED    => ["physics", "chemistry", "biology"],
  YELLOW => ["Apple", "Orange"],
);
```

I want to produce this

```
my %hash3 = (
  BLUE   => ["command1", "command2", "command3", "command4"],
  GREEN  => ["Windows", "Linux", "Unix", "Mac"],
  INDIGO => ["Air", "Earth", "Sky", "Water", "Fire"],
  ORANGE => [],
  RED    => ["physics", "chemistry", "biology"],
  VIOLET => [],
  YELLOW => ["Apple", "Orange"],
);
```

The code I am trying is as follows but it throws an error. Can you please identify what I am missing?

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash1) {
  push @{$hash3{$key}} @{$hash2{$key}};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is

```
my %hash3 = map { $_ => $hash2{$_} } keys %hash1;
```

which takes the every key from `%hash` and pairs it with the corresponding value from `%hash2` to form `%hash3`. Accessing non-existent elements in `%hash2` will return `undef` without further code.

**output**

```
(
  BLUE   => ["command1", "command2", "command3", "command4"],
  GREEN  => ["Windows", "Linux", "Unix", "Mac"],
  INDIGO => ["Air", "Earth", "Sky", "Water", "Fire"],
  ORANGE => undef,
  RED    => ["physics", "chemistry", "biology"],
  VIOLET => undef,
  YELLOW => ["Apple", "Orange"],
)
```

---

**Update**

You asked for *"blank or undef"* for values of `%hash3` where there is no value in `%hash2`, but your requested result shows empty anonymous arrays instead. To achieve this you just need to change the code to

```
my %hash3 = map { $_ => $hash2{$_} // [] } keys %hash1;
```

which gives this output

```
(
  BLUE   => ["command1", "command2", "command3", "command4"],
  GREEN  => ["Windows", "Linux", "Unix", "Mac"],
  INDIGO => ["Air", "Earth", "Sky", "Water", "Fire"],
  ORANGE => [],
  RED    => ["physics", "chemistry", "biology"],
  VIOLET => [],
  YELLOW => ["Apple", "Orange"],
)
```

Comment: By the way, aren't "shadow" and "spirit" the fifth and sixth elements?!

Answer (score 3):

A comma is missing between the arguments of `push`.

```
push @{$hash3{$key}}, @{$hash2{$key}};
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote the following piece of code and it worked.

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash1) {
    if (exists ($hash2{$key})) {
        push @{$hash3{$key}}, @{$hash2{$key}};
    }
    else {
         $hash3{$key} = [ ];
    }
}
```